# Slack Plugin Connection Failure with Some Channels in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-slack-plugins

I'm facing connection failure with some slack channels (Not with all) in Jenkins. I'm using Jenkins version 2.303.2 and Slack Notification Plugin version 2.28. I tried by updating Jenkins and installing different Slack plugin versions like 2.39, 2.40.

This is strange that I'm having issue with some random channels and working with some Private channels and some Public channels.
[Here an example image with my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcaNr.png)